# Sharepoint integration in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sharepoint

My client has a responsive website with WordPress as a backend service using PHP and now they have a new requirement asking for Sharepoint integration with WordPress.Is there any way that we can do SharePoint integration in WordPress.

Comment: There is existing library for such purposes https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

Comment: Thanks michail but this is a library and am looking for sharepoint plugin in wordpress where that plugin connects to the sharepoint website and get the data and show that in the wordpress.

Comment: As each SharePoint has unique structure, and ever single company uses it differently, you might not find any existing plugin for such general purpose. I think that you should write your own plugin, which implements library mentioned by me. After that, you'll receive from your SharePoint info which you're looking for.